# Linter for Unity ShaderLab Syntax?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, linter

Is there a linter available for Unity ShaderLab Syntax? The closest I found is [Glslang](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/) but it doesn't support `.shader` extension. It would be great to have a linter to ensure clean code just like having [cpplint](https://github.com/google/styleguide/tree/gh-pages/cpplint) for C++ code.